# Randomly 404 error pages in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website when I click on any page of website, it is showing 404 error some times and some times it is working fine. If it will show 404 error page and then i will again reload the page then it will be worked fine.

I have checked error logs but I didn't find any errors or warnings.  I have also reset permalink but no luck.

Comment: Without your logs it's a bit difficult to help you. Perhaps you get an error or something else.

Comment: @A Jain - do you get WordPress 404 error page or the server's?

Comment: @Stony - I have checked logs  file, there is nothing about 404 error.

Comment: @Rushi - I am getting wordpress website 404 page..

Comment: @ A Jain - have you recently installed or have you written a custom plugin?

Comment: No, Let me show you, open this link in your browser https://clubface-golf.com/my-societies/society-invitation/ , you will get 404 error page and after you refresh page it works fine. Try to refresh 4-5 times, you will again get 404 error page.

Comment: There seems to be a considerable delay (with a "loading animation") before the page/404 appears... what is it doing?!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.